dired: How to disable moving the cursor horizontally?
Is there any way to to disable moving the cursor horizontally in dired mode?
For example, in this screenshot I don't want my cursor to move to y or to the file attributes. I want to keep my cursor focused on the first character of the file or directory.


Why do you want to turn off horizontal movement? In my opinion, not pressing the left and right arrow keys is the most straightforward solution; even if you accidentally hit them, the cursor will automatically align to the first character of the filename on the next vertical move.

What @shynur said. Just use n/p or the vertical arrow keys. They're designed to move to the start of the next/previous file name. (Smells like you might have an X-Y problem/question, here.)

Off the top of my head, the simplest is probably to use a post-command hook (local to the Dired buffer) to move back to desired column.
Since you want to stay on the start of the file, you're in luck - Dired already provides a function for moving there!
You can use Dired's mode hook to automatically add this post-command hook to every Dired buffer.
Putting it all together:
(defun add-dired-cursor-locking-hook ()
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'dired-move-to-filename nil t))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'add-dired-cursor-locking-hook)


I suggest using set-goal-column in dired-mode-hook so that you can trivially switch it off again by typing C-uC-xC-n
This doesn't "disable moving the cursor horizontally"; but it moves it back to the goal column after vertical movement, which may be just as good, and without the drawback of preventing you from moving horizontally if you really want to.
(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  "Used in `dired-mode-hook'."
  (setq goal-column (current-column)))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-mode-hook)

Hmm.  For some reason this doesn't play nicely with C-v and M-v in dired-mode.  I've not tried to debug that.
